# Remove paragraphs with no text

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace

Is there a way I can remove paragraphs with no text in them, but might have empty html tags in them?

For example

```
<p><strong><br></strong></p> or <p></p> or <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

would be removed but

```
<p><strong>hi<br>there</strong></p> or <p>hi there</p>
```

wouldn't be removed

Comment: What about using tidy ? http://tidy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery to loop through all p elements, then get only the text of it, trim it (so just having spaces also gets removed), and then checking if there's text in it, and if there isn't, remove it.

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().trim() == "") {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ygbnpg77/

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to do it front end wise with javascript you could do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').each(function(){
           if($(this).html().length == 0)
           {
               $(this).remove();
           }
    })

})
```

Comment: This will not work if the paragraph contains tags.  Given `<p><strong><br></strong></p>`, $(this).html() would equal `<strong><br></strong>`.